# 2008R2 Standard and Hyper-V and Ram Usage (Usable vs Available)

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, memory, team-foundation-server

A new server was purchased for our development team to start utilizing the full feature set of TFS, namely [Lab Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380687.aspx).

Because of the need for Lab Management we bought a fairly beefy machine to handle this task and to also act as a build machine.

I have been tasked to setup additional features TFS on this machine starting out with a build controller and eventually going towards a full out Lab Management setup using Hyper-V.

**My question:**
Upon initially logging I noticed that Windows is registering 64gb but only 32gb available.  I know this is a limitation because of licencing since only Standard Edition is installed.

1. Since Hyper-V is another layer that handles the virtualization of guest OS's is Hyper-V able to access this memory?  Or is Hyper-V memory usage also limited by 2008 R2 Standard?
2. If Hyper-V can somehow access this memory, is this how it should be setup?  Or should the host 2008R2 Standard be upgraded to Enterprise so the Host can utilize the full 64gb?

Before I go hog wild and using TFS I wanted to ask some experts so I don't need to reinstall the OS down the road to utilize the additional 32gb.

Thanks for any help or links you can share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyper-V only see's what the host OS sees.  You need Enterprise or Datacenter edition to see more then 32GB of RAM.  I recommend a reinstall or you'll be waisting 32GB of RAM.  Sounds like a nice lab box!

Comment: +1 Also, Hyper-V Server (a separate free product from MS) can handle up to 1TB of RAM.

Comment: thanks for the information, I sort of figured that was the case.